# Angular - How to change the $scope property value via the function in the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I change the $scope property value via the function in the $scope?

html,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">{{greeting}}</div>
```

angular,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
    $scope.greeting = "Hi";
    $scope.sayHello = function() {
        return $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
    };
});
```

Result,

```
Hi
```

What I expect,

```
Hello World
```

Or, can I add properties to $scope via function?

```
app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
    $scope.sayHello = function() {
        return $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
    };
});
```

html,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">{{greeting}}</div>
```

I get nothing...

Any ideas?

Comment: where you call the function sayHallo

Comment: can I call it like this - `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">{{sayHello(); greeting}}</div>`?

Comment: ya sure you call like this get call sayhello refer to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, `$scope.greeting` is defined inside the `$scope.sayHello` function so there is no scope property called `greeting` until `sayHello()` function execute.

execute the functin and `greeting` will be available in the `HTML`

```
app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
    $scope.sayHello = function() {
        return $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
    };

    //execute the function after execution greeting will be available in the html
    $scope.sayHello();
});
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y5CnaCn75uFov9Q67gRb?p=preview)

it doesn't matter `return` or `not return` anything

inside that function

```
 return $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
```

first `$scope.greeting` assign the value so then after this there will have the `$scope.greeting` to the html.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to return the assignment, simply set the `$scope` property and it will work.

Update your method to:

```
$scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You all need to do is:

html,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">{{sayHello()}}</div>
```

angular,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
    $scope.greeting = "Hi";
    $scope.sayHello = function() {
        return $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
    };
});
```

I hope it will solve your problem